# How to install CakePHP in xampp?

Tags: cakephp, xampp

I am very new to CakePHP and want to know how to install it. Also, can you tell me if the installation process is similar to Joomla! installation. Does CakePHP have an administration interface?

Comment: See documentation. this is link to the book http://book.cakephp.org/

Comment: cake is nothing like joomla. its not a cms, but rather a framework.

Comment: yep, if you expect Cake to be similar to Joomla, Cake might not be what you're looking for.

Comment: As said, Cake is more a framework than a cms. That means it's closer to raw programming than interface configuration, but it's way more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

cakephp has administration options. Please put the whole installation in the apps folder on your web-server. Point your browser to the folder i.e. If using a local server, 127.0.0.1/index.php/

Follow the instructions shown.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a cakephp based cms you can use [croogo](http://croogo.org/)

On Windows:
In xampp the public directory is httdocs. There you copy the cake directory. In the webbrowser you call it with "http://localhost/[your_cakedirectory]" ...

You have to read the sections of [installations](http://book.cakephp.org/view/912/Installation) in the cookbook.